# Binding pageinit for specific page in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two pages in a JQuery-Mobile app, the first of which links to the second.  I have a form on the second page that loads some html dynamically based upon information from a php script, and I'd like to attach event handlers to some of the dynamically added elements once everything for that page has loaded.  I believe this lends itself to using pageinit as this is called once the ajax call for the second page has been completed.  But how do you do this for only a single page, as I don't want to load the script for every pageinit event, because it will reference not yet created elements?

I have something like:

```
$('#page_two').bind("pageinit",function(){//some code});
```

However, this doesn't execute the code inside the function body.  I tried using .live instead and this did work the way I wanted, but I've read that this is deprecated in JQuery.  Is there a way to load javascript only for a specific page in JQuery Mobile?  Also, if someone could explain why .bind didn't work, but .live did, that would be great.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: bind it with .on(, also cehech that pageinit is event you want to use, few of them starts at different times of page loading.

Comment: .bind() does not work because it binds only to elements existing at that time. As #page_two is not in the DOM yet when you do your binding, it has no effect. .live() and .on() allow you to bind to DOM elements matching the selector, wether or not they exist at the time of the binding

Comment: That makes sense.  For some reason the events still don't fire if I use .on().  What would be the causes of .live and .on working differently? @Romain  Would something like $(document).on('click','#page_two',function(){..}) work better than using the id in the selector?

Comment: Actually .on() can behave either as live() or bind(€ depending on how you use it. You should take a look at this excellent article http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I'm late but I do it this way:

```
$( document ).delegate(".yourpageclass", "pageshow", function() {
alert ("Ciao!");
});
```

I hope it'll be of help for somebody.